# Why I fail to delete the space of the string?

Tags: c++, string

I want to remove the space in a string, but when I ran my program and entered "hello world"，it did not talk to me. It crashed, which showed:

[image]

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin,str);
    int space;
    while(str.find(' ')>=0) {//something wrong happened in the loop
        space = str.find(' ');
        str.erase(space,1);
    }
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused exceedingly, because I don't know why my string is out of range.So how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know why my program crashed rather than how to remove the space.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`: That's a no-no...

Comment: I see,thanks for your reminding.

Comment: Your while-loop is infinite.

Comment: Extending on @KemyLand with a bit more reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h . It's a bad idea, but adding `using namespace std`, you have not only the entire standard library included, but it's ALL in the global namespace. That's a hell of a minefield to work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

So the real question was why does it throws an error.
std::out_of_range exception is thrown when an index that is not in the range of the container is accessed.

As mentioned in the comments the problem lies in `while(str.find(' ')>=0)`. `string::find` returns `string::npos` when it finds nothing.
`string::npos` is defined as `-1`, but since it's a `size_t` type, it can't be less that 0. So instead the value is the largest possible unsigned int because it "loops" on its type.

So it will be `4294967295`, or whatever value is the maximum for a `size_t` type on your system and with your compilation flags.

Back to the problem `while(str.find(' ')>=0)`, as said the return of `str.find` will always be a positive value, so you never stop looping and finally get an `std::out_of_range`exception because you try to access `str[string::npos]` which is not possible.

The "better' while would then be: `while(str.find(' ') != string::npos)`

**Initial answer:**

There is another way to do this using [std::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm. It provides a range to std::erase.

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "this is a line";

    std::cout << "before: " << str << std::endl;

    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());

    std::cout << "after: " << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still want to know why my program crashed rather than how to remove the space.

Comment: str.find always return a value >= 0.
When it does not find a character it returns  `string::npos`, so your code should be `while (str.find(' ') != string::npos)`

Comment: Well, it's very kind of you :) . But string::npos is defined with a value of -1. And that's why i'm so confused.

Comment: Well, yes and no, it's specified that's it's defined as -1 with a size_t type, so it's actually the largest possible value of an unsigned int.

Comment: Er, it's difficult for me to understand your words, but I'll try my best.

Comment: A value of -1 is outside the range of valid indexes for your string, hence the out of range error.

Comment: Basically `size_t` is a typedef of `unsigned int`, as its name hints an unsigned int can't be less than 0. So when you do `unsigned int value = -1` it "loops" and assign `4294967295` instead. Note that this value depends on your system, it's just for the sake of this example.

Comment: I'd pad out that comment with a wee bit more explanation and add it to the answer because that is the answer